# Change bootstrap active menu item color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the background color of active element in menu. I've tried a lot of solutions but i still can't do this. 
Menu and css:

```css
/* MAIN SITE NAVIGATION */

.navbar.navbar-default {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #323232;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #50A0FF;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #50A0FF;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav li .active {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Pokaż MENU</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[Menu photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpy7V.png)

i hope somebody will help me. ps sorry for my english :)

Comment: If you're trying to change the link background to _red_ as the last line of your CSS indicates, just follow the same pattern as your other rules: `.navbar-default .navbar-nav >.active > a {  background-color: red; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You are already doing that in your example. The problem is you are adding a while #ffffff background. Just change it to a different one.

This is your class sample

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #50A0FF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; // change this to some color other than white
}
```

you also need to add this style in your style.css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a {
    background-image: initial;
}
```

```css
/* MAIN SITE NAVIGATION */
.navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #323232;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #50A0FF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li .active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Pokaż MENU</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I noticed that this line of code just doesn't work... You can change font color but not background color

Comment: But in the updated snippet , the background is changing to black. Is same not happening with your actual code?

Comment: but snippet doesn't have bootstrap library

Comment: i have updated the answer as per your code , just add this class .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a {
    background-image: initial;
} in your style.css

Comment: @AleksanderWoźnica dod you check the solution. Its working on the dropbox code you have provided in some other comment

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #50A0FF;
    background-color: #ebebeb !important;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work too :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try using following for your elements you want to change background color

```
       .active a{
               background-color: green !important;
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: ok maybe there is a problem in rest of your code. because it is working perfectly for the code you have given. can you set up a fiddle of your full html and css code or upload your files on zippyshare.com  and send me the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q289618zyw2sr1q/bootstraptest.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Guys i've removed this line

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
```

and now it is working :)